# Tengo problemas con el height total de la página, cuando le pongo 100%, aparece como si fuera "0"

Tags: html, css

(Por otro lado, tengo un problema nuevamente con el height de los divs dentro del "HEADER"), les dejo el código :

```css
    body{
 
 padding-top: 0rem;
    padding-bottom: 0rem;
    height:1200px;
 width:100%;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 
    }
    
    #container{
 
 height: 97%;
 width: 95%;
 background-color: grey;
 

    }
    
    /*Small devices (phones)*/
    @media only screen and (max-width: 600px){
     
 body{
  background-color: red;
 }
 
 #Header{
  width:100%;
  height:15%;
 }
  #logo{
   background-color:blue;
   width:100%;
   height:80%:
  }
  #nav{
   width:100%;
   height:20%;
  }
 #About{
  width:100%;
  height:30%;
 }
 #TopTrendings{
  width:100%;
  height:35 %;
 }
 #Who{
  width:100%;
  height:10%;
 }
 #Contact{
  width:100%;
  height:10%;
 }
  

    }
```

```html
 <div id="container"> 
 
  <header id="Header"> 
  
   <div id="logo">  </div>
   
   <div id="nav">
   
    <table id="NavElements"> 
   
     <td id="Inicio">Inicio</td>
     <td id="QueEs">¿Qué es?</td>
     <td id="NavTopTrendings">Tops</td>
     <td id="Explora"> Explora</td>
     <td id="Nosotros">Nosotros</td>

    </table>
  
   </div>
   
  </header>
  <div id="About"> </div>
  <div id="TopTrendings"> </div>
  <div id="Who"> </div>
  <div id="Contact"> </div>
 
 </div>
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema con los `div` dentro del `header`?

Answer (score 1):

`html` no tiene una medida definida, por lo tanto está tomando el porcentaje de una altura no definida.

```
html, body {
     height: 100%;
}
```

te recomiendo usar `vh` (viewport height) debido a que toma el alto total del espacio disponible en la pantalla, siendo una medida relativa, permitiendo al `body` ocupar todo ese espacio. En lo personal, recomiendo usar para el body definir su alto en `vh` y ancho en `vw` (viewport width) y usar % porcentajes con los hijos.

```
body {
    height: 100vh;
}
```